# Как войти в почту и прочитать последние сообщения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap

Всем привет. Хотелось бы прочитать сообщения на Python используя *imaplib*

Comment: вот тут наверняка дубликаты найдутся: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+imaplib

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin возможно да, это дубликат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, для начала войдем в нашу почту:

```py
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.ru")

imap.login('юзер', 'пароль')
```

Теперь прочитаем все сообщения из папки "Входящие":

```py
status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
```

Распечатаем все:

```py
for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)
            # if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                # iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    try:
                        # get the email body
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass
                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                        print(body)
                    elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                        
                        filename = part.get_filename()
                        if filename:
                            folder_name = clean(subject)
                            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                
                                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                            
                            open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            else:
                
                content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                # get the email body
                body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                if content_type == "text/plain":
                    # print only text email parts
                    print(body)
            if content_type == "text/html":
                # if it's HTML, create a new HTML file and open it in browser
                folder_name = clean(subject)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                    
                    os.mkdir(folder_name)
                filename = "index.html"
                filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                
                open(filepath, "w").write(body)
                
                webbrowser.open(filepath)
            print("="*100)
```

Выйдем из коннекта:

```py
imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

Весь код:

```py
# number of top emails to fetch
N = 3

# create an IMAP4 class with SSL, use your email provider's IMAP server
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.ru")
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)

# select a mailbox (in this case, the inbox mailbox)
# use imap.list() to get the list of mailboxes
status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")

# total number of emails
messages = int(messages[0])

for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            # decode email sender
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)
            # if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                # iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    try:
                        # get the email body
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass
                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                        print(body)
                    elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                        # download attachment
                        filename = part.get_filename()
                        if filename:
                            folder_name = clean(subject)
                            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                # make a folder for this email (named after the subject)
                                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                            # download attachment and save it
                            open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            else:
                # extract content type of email
                content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                # get the email body
                body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                if content_type == "text/plain":
                    # print only text email parts
                    print(body)
            if content_type == "text/html":
                # if it's HTML, create a new HTML file and open it in browser
                folder_name = clean(subject)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                    # make a folder for this email (named after the subject)
                    os.mkdir(folder_name)
                filename = "index.html"
                filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                # write the file
                open(filepath, "w").write(body)
                # open in the default browser
                webbrowser.open(filepath)
            print("="*100)
# close the connection and logout
imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Минимальный пример того, как можно прочитать все сообщения:

```py
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

USER: str = ''
PASSWORD: str = ''
HOST: str = ''

with IMAP4_SSL(HOST) as M:
    M.login(USER, PASSWORD)
    M.select()
    typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
```